# Calling connect in void context is deprecated

Tags: perl, ssh

I am trying to use the
[`Net::SSH2`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH2)
in the following the Perl code, but I am getting this error.

> Calling connect in void context is deprecated at test.pl line 9.
>   Net::SSH2: failed to connect to xx.xx.xxx.xx:ssh: Bad file descriptor at test.pl line 9.

```
use strict;

use Net::SSH2;
#use Net::SSH2::Expect;

#my $Hostname = 'xx.xx.xx.xx';

my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();

#$ssh->timeout(10);

$ssh->connect('xx.xx.xx.xx');
```

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: It wants you to use: `$ssh->connect('xx.xx.xx.xx') or $ssh->die_with_error;`

Comment: The deprecation warning is because Net::SSH2 wants you to check the return value of `connect`. It suggests to do `$ssh->connect( ... ) or ssh2->die_with_error`. Since you're not doing that, it `die`s itself directly, and also issues the warning. The _Bad file descriptor_ error is your real problem.

Comment: @simbabque, "*The Bad file descriptor error is your real problem*", Not so sure. I think printing the void context warning might clobber the error. The OP should start by adding `or $ssh->die_with_error` and running the program again. Furthermore, in void context, it always says "failed to connect" even when that's not the problem.

Comment: @simbabque, I know. What's your point?

Comment: @simbabque, Printing to the screen is a library or system call. It therefore makes `errno` (`$!`) meaningless (unless `warnif` explicitly backs up and restores `errno`).

Comment: Fixed the issue. Kept the code inside "if".
if($ssh->connect('xx.xx.xx.xx')){
print "successfully connected";
}

Comment: @simbabque, Just checked. `warnif` can indeed clobber `$!`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put the new code and an updated error message in it Sujeet.

Comment: @simbaque: Do you want me to edit the question with the changes that I have made to fix the isusse ??

Comment: Oh, if you're already done, then no. Write up your own answer if you want.

Comment: @SujeetPadhi: Please write up an *answer* that shows what you did.

Comment: I've had to fix a couple of your posts now. Please read [*Markdown help*](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and possibly [*Markdown: Syntax*](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) and learn to use markdown properly,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the connect method inside if or using die_with_error helped me fixed the code.

```
use strict;

use Net::SSH2;

my $ssh=Net::SSH2->new();

if($ssh->connect('xx.xx.xx.xx'))
  {
     print "successfully connected";

     $ssh->auth_password('username','password') or $ssh->die_with_error;

  }
```

Comment: When `connect` fails, your code still calls `auth_password` anyway. That makes no sense.